# Apache Kafka Producter - Consumer Web Services

Tags: json, api, web-services, apache-kafka

First of all, I want to thank that person who takes the time to read and offer me some idea about this difficulty that I am having.

In the company where I am working, we are carrying out some innovation projects with APIs that will be used internally. We chose to use Apache Kafka for the queuing of requests submitted by users. Unfortunately none of us had a previous knowledge of Kafka and everything touched with research.

Now to be concrete, I need some collaboration with the following:

I need that when the Producer server makes a request, the consumer server reads it and depending on the request, executes a web services that will generate a result in JSON format and return that result to the Producer.

So far I have managed to make the communication between a producer server and a consumer server, but with simple messages ..Somethink like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frT4a.jpg)

Questions:

- How to make the consumer depending on the request that I have, I run a Web Services?
- How to make the result in JSON format of the execution of that Web Services be returned to the producer? And in the same order in which the requests were made?

I greatly appreciate the collaboration, this topic has been confusing for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Consumers don't send data back to the Producer in Kafka, so are you sure you're researching the correct tools?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the answer. At the moment I thought that Apache Kafka was a good option, although I'm not entirely sure. I understand then that the consumer can not send messages to the producer, but can the consumer send results of the requests to another server? Or do you have in mind some tool that you can recommend me to perform this procedure that I need? Thank you!

Comment: In Kafka, you have producers and consumers. A consumer application, can also produce an event as a result (just make sure your events are non-cyclic). To ensure ordering, just make sure your events are routed to the same partition. consumers are guaranteed to read from a single partition in the same order that the events were produced.